# Format of GET Request

Tags: php, arduino

I have an external server running MySQL. I have installed a PHP script that, when accessed from HTTP, will deliver data from one of the tables.

It works fine from within a browser:

```
http://www.seti.net/php/getEvents.php
```

But I cannot figure out how to sent this command from an Arduino. I have the `EthernetClient` library working and can access Google as in the example. When I send this command through the client:

```
client.println("//GET /php/getEvents.php HTTP/1.0");
```

the server returns:

```
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Implemented</h1>
<p>GET to /php/getEvents.php not supported.<br />
```

What is the correct way to format a GET in Arduino?

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
client.println("GET /php/getEvents.php HTTP/1.0");
```

**updated**

```
  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /php/getEvents.php HTTP/1.0");
    client.println("Host: www.seti.net");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  } 
  else {
    // if you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.println("connection failed");
  }
```

Comment: Yes - That does work but Ihad to add:
client.println("Host: www.seti.net"); and

Comment: client.println("Connection: close\r\n");
BUT - Why does it work.  Do you have a reference I can read more about this?  Thanks.

Comment: @SetiNet There are many [Examples](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage). Follow them. if my answer is helpful to you, accept it as correct answer. then it will be helpful to other users who has same question.

Comment: Yes the answer is correct but I don't see how to 'check off' that it is. Where in StackOverFlow is the check box?

Comment: @SetiNet left side of the answer, below the vote buttons, there is a **Right mark symbol**. click it.